# How to use temp table for ETL during populating Star schema?

Tags: database, etl, data-warehouse, star-schema, fact-table

I have the scripts to pull data from RDBMS and populate the Data warehouse. It works. I was wondering how Temp table comes in between. What are the steps to ETL exactly? Even though my data warehouse is populated, my teacher says that we need to use a temp table. why is it important?

Please help me. I am very confused right now. Thank you.

We need to pull the data from the databases of two different offices in two different locations. I will give the details of the table below.

> **lds_job_role**
>
> job_role_id:integer
>  job_role_desc:varchar
>   key_skill_1:INEGER
>  key_skill_2:INEGER
>  key_skill_3:INEGER
>   recommended_sal:INTEGER
>
> **lds_account**
>
> account_id:INTEGER
>  acc_name:VARCHAR
>  acc_postcode:VARCHAR
>
> **lds_placement**
>
> placement_id:INTEGER
>  plt_short_desc: VARCHAR
>   plt_required_start_date:DATE
>  plt_estimated_end_date:DATE
>   plt_actual_start_date:DATE
>  plt_renewal_no:INTEGER
>   plt_to_permanent:VARCHAR
>  max_salary: INTEGER
>   min_salary:INTEGER
>  actual_salary:INTEGER
>
> **mch_job_role**
>
> job_role_id:INTEGER
>  job_role_desc:VARCHAR
>   recommended_sal:INTEGER
>
> **mch_account**
>
> account_id:INTEGER
>  acc_name:VARCHAR
>  acc_postcode:VARCHAR
>
> **mch_placement**
>
> placement_id:INTEGER
>  plt_short_desc:INTEGER
>   plt_required_start_date:DATE
>  plt_estimated_end_date:DATE
>   plt_actual_start_date:DATE
>  plt_actual_end_date:DATE
>   plt_renewal_no:INTEGER
>  plt_to_permanent:VARCHAR
>   max_salary:INTEGER
>  min_salary:INTEGER
>   actual_salary:INTEGER
>  supervisor_name:VARCHAR
>
> Below are the facts and dimensions of the Star schema:
>
> **job_roe_dim**
>
> job_role_id
>  job_role_desc
>
> **time_dim**
>
> time_id
>  year
>
> **account_dim**
>
> account_id
>  account_name
>
> **fact_accounts**
>
> Report_id
>  no_of_placements
>  salary
>  FK1_time_id
>   FK2_account_id
>  FK3_job_role_id

The exercise tells us to "deal with data quality issues, measures for FACTs, identifiers etc ". I THINK I have already done that with the scripts, but I do not know how to show it. Perhaps that is why the the temp table is required?

Comment: You don't necessarily _need_ to use a temp table, but it might be useful depending on the characteristics of the table you are loading. Can you share some more details about the exercise, and I'll be able to give you a proper answer.

Comment: I will update the question to add a few more details.

Comment: Perhaps your teacher is confusing temp tables with _staging_ tables. Among other reasons, I use _staging_ tables to debug data flows. By no means do you 'need' to use a staging table. ETL actually means Extract-Transform-Load, which means you transform the data in-flow _without_ a staging table. There is another specific acronym "ELT" which means Extract-Load-Transform which means you extract data and load into a table _then_ transform it.. So this acronym specifically describes a process that uses staging tables.As usual the teachers doing the teaching don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: Thank you! Ill just insert the data into temporary tables and then copy it from the tables to my facts and dimensions.